# How to Request a Driver Be Included in 16.10 and Up rtl8812AU

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, netgear

I love Linux and use it for 99% of all of my work. I am using a Netgear wireless AC600 USB adapter that uses the rtl8812AU driver. This card does a decent job, but often when I run updates I have to recompile the driver. Since dongles like this allow us to extend the life of old computers, with failed internal cards, etc. I was wondering how to ask for this card to be supported in the next distro of Ubuntu. Recompiling the driver isn't the end of the world, but it seems like better USB adapter support would be good in may ways.

Comment: You can DKMS automatically compile it when Ubuntu downloads Kernel updates.

Comment: The package [rtl8812au-dkms](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/rtl8812au-dkms) in 16.10 and 16.04 looks like exactly what you want. Have you tried installing?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. This works great. Sorry it took me so long to respond.

Answer (score 4):

There is [rtl8812au-dkms](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/rtl8812au-dkms), which seems to be the driver you want. It's available for 16.04, 16.10 and 17.04.